# Revising selection sort: output shows weird signs instead of sorted array?

Tags: arrays, sorting

So here is my problem. I enter 10 numbers, and the array should sort it so that the largest number comes first, and then the next largest and so on.
When I get the output, it shows some weird signs. Can anyone help please?

Thank you. //Daniel

```
package revising_selection_sort;

import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Revising_selection_sort {

    public static double[] selectionSort(double[] list) {

        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            double currentMax = list[i];
            int currentMaxIndex = i;

            for (int j = i + 1; j < list.length; j++) {
                if (currentMax < list[j]) {
                    currentMax = list[j];
                    currentMaxIndex = j;

                }

            }
            if (currentMaxIndex != i) {
                list[currentMaxIndex] = list[i];
                list[i] = currentMax;
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double arr[] = new double[10];

        int num1;
        int num2;
        int num3;
        int num4;
        int num5;
        int num6;
        int num7;
        int num8;
        int num9;
        int num10;

        String nr1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Indtast 1. hele tal");
        num1 = Integer.parseInt(nr1);
        String nr2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Indtast 2. hele tal");
        num2 = Integer.parseInt(nr2);
        String nr3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Indtast 3. hele tal");
        num3 = Integer.parseInt(nr3);
        String nr4 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Indtast 4. hele tal");
        num4 = Integer.parseInt(nr4);
        String nr5 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Indtast 5. hele tal");
        num5 = Integer.parseInt(nr5);
        String nr6 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Indtast 6. hele tal");
        num6 = Integer.parseInt(nr6);
        String nr7 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Indtast 7. hele tal");
        num7 = Integer.parseInt(nr7);
        String nr8 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Indtast 8. hele tal");
        num8 = Integer.parseInt(nr8);
        String nr9 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Indtast 9. hele tal");
        num9 = Integer.parseInt(nr9);
        String nr10 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Indtast 10. hele tal");
        num10 = Integer.parseInt(nr10);

        arr[0] = num1;
        arr[1] = num2;
        arr[2] = num3;
        arr[3] = num4;
        arr[4] = num5;
        arr[5] = num6;
        arr[6] = num7;
        arr[7] = num8;
        arr[8] = num9;
        arr[9] = num10;

        String result;
        result = String.format("The sorted array is: " + selectionSort(arr));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To see the correct sorted array output you should do following:

`Arrays.toString(arr)` after calling selectionSort(arr)

or directly

`Arrays.toString(selectionSort(arr))`

So finally it would look like this:

```
result = String.format("The sorted array is: "
                        + Arrays.toString(selectionSort(arr)));
```

Moreover you do not need to return anything from your `selectionSort(double[] list)` method as you are modifying the `list` array itself.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem and the program works perfectly now! :)
Can you tell me more about this "Arrays." ? I had to fix import before it worked. What does it do? (I have to explain if the teacher asks me hehe ;) )

Comment: @Daniel It creates the String representation of the array passed to it. Look at this link for details: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(double[]).

Comment: @Daniel, Also remember to "accept answer" if it helped you solve the problem else your accept-rate will go down witch may make it harder for you to get help in the future.